# passing file path to youtube-dl in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, subprocess, youtube-dl

Im using python `subprocess.call()` to call `[youtube-dl.exe][1]` and passing parameters like so

```
downloadLocation = "-o " + "C:/Users/username/Documents/Youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s"

subprocess.call(["youtube-dl",
                 "-f" "bestvideo[ext=mp4, height=1080]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4, height=1080]/best",
                 downloadLocation,
                 url])
```

But the result is(on python console): `[download] Destination:  C#\Users\username\Documents\Youtube\myVideoFile.mp4`

And the files are getting downloaded in the current directory from where the python call is made.

Example: `"C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pytest\ C#\Users\username\Documents\Youtube"`

It looks like to me it's unable to escape the ":" character in the file path.

Please help

Comment: You need to pass flags (`-f`, `-o`) and their values separately. I.e. instead of `downloadLocation,` you need `'-o', "C:/Users/username/Documents/Youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s",`.

Comment: there's a python version, where it would be even simpler: `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Comment: Try to use a raw string for your path: `r"C:/Users/username/Documents/Youtube/%(title)s.%(ext)s"`

Comment: @Rawing it doesn't work that way either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Here's how i got it to work

```
subprocess.call(["youtube-dl",
                 "-f" "bestvideo[ext=mp4, height=1080]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4, height=1080]/best",
                 "-o" "%s" %downloadLocation,
                 "--ignore-errors",
                 url])
```